# Add text box to wearable screen - beginner

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is the code I'm using to read the heart rate from a wearable :

```
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.activity.WearableActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.hardware.*;
import android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout.*;

public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private TextView mTextViewHeart;
    SensorManager mSensorManager;
    Sensor mHeartRateSensor;
    SensorEventListener sensorEventListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);


        mTextViewHeart = new TextView(this);
        mTextViewHeart.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        mTextViewHeart.setText("heart rate ");

        mSensorManager = ((SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE));
        mHeartRateSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE);
       // mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mHeartRateSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        Log.i(TAG, "LISTENER REGISTERED.");
        mTextViewHeart.setText("Something here");

        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mHeartRateSensor, mSensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

       // mSensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, mHeartRateSensor, mSensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }


    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAccuracyChanged - accuracy: " + accuracy);
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE) {
            String msg = "" + (int)event.values[0];
            mTextViewHeart.setText(msg);
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
        }
        else
            Log.d(TAG, "Unknown sensor type");
    }

}
```

main_activity.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.wearable.view.DotsPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/page_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_background">
    </android.support.wearable.view.DotsPageIndicator>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The sensor functionality seems fine. The text boxes are not being displayed on screen, instead I just receive a blank screen. How to add `mTextViewHeart` to the screen programmatically ? Or is required that I add it via `main_activity.xml` ?

Update :

```
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.activity.WearableActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.hardware.*;
import android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout.*;

public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private TextView mTextViewHeart;
    SensorManager mSensorManager;
    Sensor mHeartRateSensor;
    SensorEventListener sensorEventListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout )findViewById(R.id.parent);

        mTextViewHeart = new TextView(this);
        mTextViewHeart.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        mTextViewHeart.setText("heart rate ");

        mSensorManager = ((SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE));
        mHeartRateSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE);
        Log.i(TAG, "LISTENER REGISTERED.");
        mTextViewHeart.setText("Something here");

        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mHeartRateSensor, mSensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);


        relativeLayout.addView(mTextViewHeart);

    }


    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAccuracyChanged - accuracy: " + accuracy);
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE) {
            String msg = "" + (int)event.values[0];
            mTextViewHeart.setText(msg);
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
        }
        else
            Log.d(TAG, "Unknown sensor type");
    }

}
```

main_activity.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.wearable.view.DotsPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/page_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_background">
    </android.support.wearable.view.DotsPageIndicator>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've updated with Pavneet Singh answer but blank screen displayed.

Maybe should configure all UI via XML ?

Update2 :

Updating to use linearlayout does not have an impact :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.wearable.view.DotsPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/page_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_background">
    </android.support.wearable.view.DotsPageIndicator>

</LinearLayout>

package com.example.android.wearable.datalayer;

import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.activity.WearableActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.hardware.*;
import android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout.*;

public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private TextView mTextViewHeart;
    SensorManager mSensorManager;
    Sensor mHeartRateSensor;
    SensorEventListener sensorEventListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        LinearLayout relativeLayout = (LinearLayout )findViewById(R.id.parent);

        mTextViewHeart = new TextView(this);
        mTextViewHeart.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        mTextViewHeart.setText("heart rate ");

        mSensorManager = ((SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE));
        mHeartRateSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE);
        Log.i(TAG, "LISTENER REGISTERED.");
        mTextViewHeart.setText("Something here");

        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mHeartRateSensor, mSensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);


        relativeLayout.addView(mTextViewHeart);

    }


    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAccuracyChanged - accuracy: " + accuracy);
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE) {
            String msg = "" + (int)event.values[0];
            mTextViewHeart.setText(msg);
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
        }
        else
            Log.d(TAG, "Unknown sensor type");
    }

}
```

Adding an edittext field also does not display :

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="121dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="test"
    />
```

Could the issue be something fundamental ?

Comment: the issue gonna be the constraints , your gridview pager is match parent and if you add textview in java code then you need to add constraints to your textview too  so there will be more code for constraints so i suggest either use linear layout as parent otherwise java code will have more lines than you would expect

Comment: @PavneetSingh please see new update. Seems I cannot add any UI to screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This screen layout displays :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click me to another screen" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I'm screen 1 (main.xml)"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```